# How should I assign my data models to map the JSON using Alamofire?

Tags: swift, uikit, alamofire

I am new to this, so I made some models for mapping JSON but early there are was some models to display templates, now I am going to display some real content on the views instead using `Alamofire`. It might be stupid, but how should I assign/replace the data models to make it work correctly?
Here is the `get` method:

```
friendsAPI.getFriends { [weak self] users in
                 self?.friends0 = users!  // here is the crash happens because there are two different data models - `FriendModel` and `UserModel`
                 self?.tableView.reloadData()
                 print(users)
             }
```

There are `UserModel` I have used to display some content on the different views:

```
struct UserModel: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: UserModel, rhs: UserModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.userSurname == rhs.userSurname
    }
    
    let userFirstName: String
    let userSurname: String
    let userPhoto: UIImage?
    var userPhotos: [UIImage]
    let userAge: Int
    let id: Int
}
```

And now there are `FriendModel` using to parse JSON:

```
// MARK: - FriendsResponse
 
 class FriendsResponse: Codable {
     let response: FriendsModel
 }

 // MARK: - Response

 class FriendsModel: Codable {
     let count: Int
     let items: [FriendModel]
 }

 // MARK: - Item

 class FriendModel: Codable {
     let id: Int
     let lastName, trackCode, firstName: String
     let photo100: String

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case id
         case lastName = "last_name"
         case trackCode = "track_code"
         case firstName = "first_name"
         case photo100 = "photo_100"
     }
 }
```

In the most of my app I have used `UserModel` to handle and display content.
So, how should I assign this data models?
P.S.: I'll be so glad if someone will help me! Thank you!

Comment: Well there is no magical way. You should generally replace variables of type `UserModel` to have `FriendModel` type and do rest of rewriting manually where needed (compiler will complain). Or to make a property/method on `FriendModel `that returns a variable of type `UserModel` that is created based on current friend model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to convert from FriendModel to UserModel:

```
struct UserModel {
    init(friend: FriendModel) {
        id = friend.id
        userFirstName = friend.firstName
        userSurname = friend.lastName
        ... // assign all the other fields as needed
    }
}
```

Then use it to convert your results:

```
friendsAPI.getFriends { [weak self] apiFriends in
    self?.friends0 = apiFriends.map({ UserModel(friend: $0) })
}
```

Here it is an init method, but feel free to put it in a normal func like `func userFromFriend(_ friend: FriendModel) -> UserModel`, and put that func wherever you want.

Comment: I can't help you with these additional questions unless you provide full code and full errors. Each of those is solvable. You can go over these yourself, or update the question with more details, or ask new questions. The code above assumes that apiFriends is an array of FriendModel-s, and friends0 is an array of UserModel-s. The type conversions are easy, you can figure it out. The String to UIImage might require you downloading that image, that deserves a separate research/question.

Comment: I worked out part of the bugs, I think I'll get to the bottom of all the bugs soon, thank you for your feedback!